# PyCharm virtualvenv RuntimeError on setting up new project environment

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

So I just want to create a new project, the other day everything worked fine, and i didnt notice any updates or so. If I today create a new project together with virtualenv (on project setup), it gives me a runtime error for setuptools saying a file was not found under the path. Following the path manually everything is existing. What could be the reason of this problem?

Python version 3.10.9

Thanks in advance.

This is the shown error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\__main__.py", line 167, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\__main__.py", line 163, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\__main__.py", line 16, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 30, in cli_run
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\run\session.py", line 43, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\run\session.py", line 56, in _seed
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 69, in run
RuntimeError: failed to build image setuptools because:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 55, in _install
    installer.install(creator.interpreter.version_info)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 35, in install
    self._sync(filename, into)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\copy.py", line 11, in _sync
    copy(src, dst)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\util\path\_sync.py", line 37, in copy
    method(str(src), str(dest))
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\util\path\_sync.py", line 48, in copytree
    shutil.copy(src_f, dest_f)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 417, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 254, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\*username*\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\Local\\pypa\\virtualenv\\wheel\\3.10\\image\\1\\CopyPipInstall\\setuptools-65.5.1-py3-none-any\\setuptools\\config\\_validate_pyproject\\extra_validations.py'
```